# Use Elastic Search with RabbitMQ

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, elasticsearch-river

I have a RabbitMQ Queue that ingest some docs that needs to be transferred to Elastic Search.

How do I create the Elastic Search as a consumer, so that ES acts a consumer to the docs Queue.

Possible options :

1. Using RabbitMQ River ?
2. Using RabbitMQ Plugin ? (How to do this )
3. Other ?

Can someone post an example ?

Answer (score 4):

at your ELK create config file /etc/logstash/conf.d/anyfile.conf

```
input {
   rabbitmq {
      host => 'rabbit.example.com'
      queue => 'my_queue_name'
      exchange => "my_exchange_name"
      key => 'my_logs'
      durable => true
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      host => "elk.example.com"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for a [RabbitMQ river](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-rabbitmq), here is an example, although you should note that [rivers will be deprecated soon](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers) (i.e. as of ES 1.5) and the other solution by Prameswar Lal using Logstash will be preferred.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_river/custom_river_name/_meta -d '{
    "type" : "rabbitmq",
    "rabbitmq" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5672,
        "user" : "guest",
        "pass" : "guest",
        "vhost" : "/",
        "queue" : "elasticsearch",
        "exchange" : "elasticsearch",
        "routing_key" : "elasticsearch",
        "exchange_declare" : true,
        "exchange_type" : "direct",
        "exchange_durable" : true,
        "queue_declare" : true,
        "queue_bind" : true,
        "queue_durable" : true,
        "queue_auto_delete" : false,
        "heartbeat" : "30m",
        "qos_prefetch_size" : 0,
        "qos_prefetch_count" : 10,
        "nack_errors" : true
    },
    "index" : {
        "bulk_size" : 100,
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms",
        "ordered" : false,
        "replication" : "default"
    }
}
```